# Slack Dock Icon shows open Firefox windows

Tags: unity, gnome, firefox, dock, slack

When I have Slack opened and launch a new Firefox instance, the dock indicator and preview for that new Firefox instance shows on the Slack dock icon.
[image]

### System info

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have resolved itself with latest apt update